# Value to string in repeat loop not updating value

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I'm practicing with the **Repeat Loop** in **Blender 4.0** since the release is in about a week or so.

I'm trying to convert the **scale value to text (a string) so it will show the new radius / diameter value of the scaled cylinder**.

When the scale value is converted to a text (a string) the **value does not change**. I've tried it multiple ways but **the string value does not change even though the scale of the cylinder does**.

See images with arrows and blend file below.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

The initial scale value is **0.6** of the cylinders but the text should be going down (**example: 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3**) but they all stay at **0.6**. **I would like to print the scale value so I can convert that to show the new radius / diameter of the cylinder in mm**.

**Note: I was told I have to multiply scale by factor for each repeat** but I thought I was doing that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't change the scale value at all in your loop, that's why it stays always the same.

Try this:

[image]

Note: i did not make a correct xyz movement of the text, because i just wanted to see "something". So you have to do that on your own, but at least you will now see "something". One more thing: of course you have to turn the switch off so that the geometry will be added at all.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up requiring more thought than I expected.  I've done something like this in python which is a little easier but geometry nodes will allow it to be more flexible (for my needs).

Just to let you know this will be used to create 3D printed calibration objects to make / test press fit snapped shapes / objects to make sure the sizes and geometry will fit together correct.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

blend file below.
[image]